# How to store password in a table on Redshift?

Tags: database, rdbms, amazon-redshift

Is there any method to store the password of the user in encrypted format on Redshift database table?

Answer (score 2):

You will find list of existing users with their password ( Not the password -always reads as ******** ) by below query

```
select * from PG_USER
```

The pg_shadow table has actual password stored.if you are superuser then you can access this table.
it has column passed.

If the password is encrypted, this column will begin with the string md5 followed by a 32-character hexadecimal MD5 hash. The MD5 hash will be of the user's password concatenated to their user name. For example, if user joe has password xyzzy, PostgreSQL will store the md5 hash of xyzzyjoe. A password that does not follow that format is assumed to be unencrypted.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can we decrypt it? . is there any option?

Comment: Note in redshift you can not actually view the pg_shadow table as AWS does not give your root user access to this table. Only in stand alone postgres can you view this table

Comment: I think I missed out on understanding a few bits of it. Can you please put some light on how to build a user table (not redshift users but an application user) where I want to encrypt the password column exactly like PG_USER table.